# Admob crashes our app with NullPointerException in DeviceMotionService

Tags: android, webview, admob

Our app gets lots NullPointerException in DeviceMotionService. We don't have WebView in our app, it seems it is related with Admob SDK. How can I workaround the problem to prevent crashes?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.DeviceMotionService$2.run(DeviceMotionService.java:103)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:734)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

[Here is Google Groups discussion about the crashes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/4i-j2BURawQ)

Comment: known issue looks like, take a look at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54877

Comment: It seems somehow they revived the bug last week because there was not flood of app crashes before last week.

Comment: you might want to add that in google tracker to get it reopen

Comment: Im having the exact same issue, hundreds of crashes per day on Androids 4.1.x and some 4.0.x.

Comment: @rottz Do you use Admob mediation for facebook ads?

Comment: @Tony no Facebook or any other ads through mediation, only pure Admob ads.